# How do I ask my table columns to be printed in a alphabetical manner

Tags: mysql

`desc foo`; prints all the columns.

How do I make it list all the columns in a alphabetical manner

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [information_schema](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/columns-table.html) for that, depending on exactly what you want displayed.

Something like:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, IS_NULLABLE, COLUMN_DEFAULT
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE table_name = 'foo'
  AND table_schema = 'foo_schema'
  ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME;
```

Comment: @Jason: in the `WHERE` you can (or should) add `AND table_schema = 'your_schema'`

Answer (score 1):

The ANSI INFORMATION_SCHEMA tables  [(in this case, INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/columns-table.html) provide more flexibility in MySQL:

> SELECT c.column_name   FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c  WHERE
>   c.table_name = 'tbl_name'
>   -- AND c.table_schema = 'db_name'
>   ORDER BY c.column_name